Creating a "pie diagram" infographic in Python
How would I create an infographic/diagram like the one found here using Python.  I can't even find the name of this diagram type to be able to search for information - Is it a "proportional area chart pie"?
I've heard that such diagrams can be made in Tableau, but I don't have access to it.

Related, but square and with javascript: Proportional Area Chart (Square) with d3.js.  In Python there is also a squarify package. Note that your question is a bad fit for StackOverflow: you add two different library tags and you don't provide code nor test data.

I looked into the creator of that image and it appears that she's a graphic designer and I wouldn't be surprised if that chart was made by hand, not by a convenient python package. But if you're looking for an alternative way to show relative proportions of data I'd look into variations of pie charts or hierarchical charts like this. Also, I haven't seen anything in Tableau that's capable of doing what's in that image.
